# I am using the React-Native Share.But isn't supported in Web.It gives the following error. Error: Share is not supported in this browser

Tags: react-native, expo, share, expo-web, react-native-share

i am I am using the **React-Native Share**. But isn't supported in Web. It gives the following error.

> Error: Share is not supported in this browser

How can i use it with browser support?

```
const onShare = async () => {
    try {
      // console.log(data);

      const result = await Share.share({
        message: `WSLRemit transfer receipt\n\nTransfer number: ${Transaction?.manual_payment_ref} \nThey get: ${Transaction?.recipient_gets} ${Transaction?.target_currency}\nYou sent: ${Transaction?.nominal}  ${Transaction?.source_currency}\nTotal paid:  ${Transaction?.total}  ${Transaction?.source_currency}`,
      });

      if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
        if (result.activityType) {
          // shared with activity type of result.activityType
        } else {
          // shared
        }
      } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
        // dismissed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // alert(error.message);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Import it from 'react-native'

like

```
import {
  Share
} from "react-native";
```

it will work on web as-well.

Comment: Already use like it but gives the same error.

Comment: share your webpack.config

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the site using ssl and it only appears to work on a mobile device. I couldn't get it to work on desktop at all.

For example, for expo you can run it like this:

`expo start --https`